# Were Japanese names ever anglicised?

Tags: translation, history, names

Nowadays, Japanese people usually keep their names as is, except using the Latin alphabet, and having their given name before their surname, when they're in English-speaking countries.

By contrast, many immigrants into English-speaking countries, even those from countries with European languages, had their names [Anglicised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicisation_of_names#Immigration_to_English-speaking_countries), and it still goes on today, at least with native speakers of Chinese.

Did Japanese people, or their descendants, use to anglicise their names, especially before, during or soon after WWII?

Comment: If this is more suitable for english.SE, feel free to migrate it there.

Comment: Anecdata: [Fred Korematsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Korematsu) (of Korematsu v. United States) had a name of "Fred" from birth.

Comment: It makes things a little more difficult than with Europeans in that English doesn't have related names (eg Wilhelm > William), but I suppose they could do the Chinese thing and either pick a name that sounds a bit like theirs or pick a name that's totally unrelated to their real name.

Comment: "had a name of "Fred" from birth"? Where does it say that?

Comment: The Wikipedia article says he called himself Clyde Sarah to avoid internment, which suggests Fred was his real name.

Comment: I would say more likely they were "Portuguecised"... as you would probably need a larger Japanese diaspora or someone famous that others would follow. [Tizuka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tizuka_Yamasaki) is seemingly a newly devised Brazilian name with Japanese origin (there is no mention that this name is not on her birth certificate, so it probably can be called "Brazilian name"). But to claim it was -cized you would need more than one person with such a name.

Comment: Besides, this comment about Fred Korematsu - how does it relate to the question? Do other people named Toyosaburo use Fred now? Like many Dimitroses choosing Jimmy? Which aspect of Anglicisation are you asking about? Many Japanese names are written in a spelling that is easier for English-speaking people just by using Hepburn romanization. But leaving aside "fu" or "hu", there are other types of romanization like "Ohta" for 太田 which are aimed at English speakers. I don't think any other European language user would pronounce it similarly to Japanese applying their native language rules.

Comment: The linguist Masayoshi Shibatani goes by "Matt".

Comment: The physicist [Toshihide Maskawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshihide_Maskawa) spells his surname in a way which would avoid an English mispronunciation.

Comment: I doubt if East Asian names can be "Anglicized", they just have separate Japanese name and English name.

Comment: Some more strange examples in the Anglosphere: Toyoda -> Toyota. Matsuda -> Mazda. Matsumoto Yukihiro (originator of Ruby) -> Matz. Suda Gouichi -> Suda 51.

Comment: @bright-star, in German, `⟨z⟩` is pronounced //t͡s//, so `Matsuda` → `Mazda` works in that context.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Good point. I was focused on the Anglicization angle, but I suppose that was a case of Germanization.

Answer (score 1):

According to this list, yes (but not uniformly. And obviously, it can't be reliably said to represent a proportional sampling).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Japanese_Americans

But it is worth noting that a lot of the non-Japanese name holders were alive during/after WWII.

Anecdotally, some of my friends (2nd & 3rd-generation Canadians of Japanese descent) have Japanese names, but with an English middle name. I don't know how wide-spread that naming practice is, but in my experience, it's not uncommon.